# Is it possible to default to zoomed in on a draw.io object in confluence?

Tags: app.diagrams.net, confluence

When adding a draw.io macro/drawing to confluence, is it possible to have the drawing zoomed in to a particular section of the drawing by default?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean in the diagram viewer in the Confluence page (i.e. the page isn't in edit mode), no. We'll [add it as a feature request](https://desk.draw.io/browse/DFC-62).